# Google Cast: Get Currently Playing Song from Audio Device

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I am trying to use the Google Cast SDK to write a tiny app.
This app should be able to show which (Google casted) song my audio system is currently playing.
This should include info about the track's title, length, artist, album etc.

Using the iOS classes I have managed to connect to the correct `GCKDevice` via the `GCKDiscoveryManager`. But how do I get the data about the track which is currently playing?

I would prefer an answer for the iOS classes, but I would also greatly appreciate any hint towards achieving the same with the Chromecast browser extension.

**Addon:**

On the Cast Developers +-Group I was pointed to [this link](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_advanced#receive_status_updates), thanks Leon!  I see that I should register a `GCKRemoteMediaClientListener` which I could do if I had a `GCKRemoteMediaClient`object. The only way to get that seems to be via a `GCKSession`. I can create such a session from scratch but then the property `remoteMediaClient` is `nil`. Or I can ask the `GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager` to start a session for me. But if I do that, the device stops playback immediately.
So I am still a bit lost about how to achieve my initial goal.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more help by Leon from the Cast Developer Group, I have figured this one out. The key information is the id of the app which is running on my audio device. I figured that out by the deprecated 2.0 API which is why I will not add this detail.
So assume you have that key, you can initialize yiur cast context by

```
let options = GCKCastOptions.init(receiverApplicationID: applicationID)
GCKCastContext.setSharedInstanceWith(options)
```

Next thing is to find your device. This was not too hard (the only thong I figured out by myself :o) and the `GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().discoveryManager`is your friend here.
If you now start a session via the `GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager` it will *not* stop the playback. Totally logical in hindsight, makes me wonder which app I started before with that random app id I used...

With the session started you can cast that session to a cast session and add a session listener.

```
if let session = sessionManager.currentSession as? GCKCastSession {
    session.add(self)
}
```

And when that session notifies its activeness as noted in

```
func castSession(_ castSession: GCKCastSession, didReceive activeInputStatus: GCKActiveInputStatus)
```

you can now find the long lost `remoteMediaClient` and register for his precious events

```
if let client = castSession.remoteMediaClient {
    client.add(self)
}
```

And this will end the long journey by calling your delegate method

```
func remoteMediaClient(_ client: GCKRemoteMediaClient, didUpdate mediaMetadata: GCKMediaMetadata)
```

And if you are as I lucky as I was that media data is quite incomplete.
Mine just contained the title and the release date and nothing else.
Thanks Deezer!

But maybe I can use some id or other obtained in the whole process to get the missing data from the Deezer server? Time will tell.

In the meantime I hope this help somebody with more luck.